# POST in a form Jquery select2

Tags: php, jquery, select, post, jquery-select2

So I am using the Select2 plugin, and am having trouble posting multiple options in a form. I am able to select multiple options but can only pass one through:

```
<form>
  <select multiple name="message-from-select" id="message-from-select" class="select2">
      <option value="janedoen@example.com">janedoen@example.com</option>
      <option value="antonius@example.com" selected="selected">antonius@example.com</option>
      <option value="michael@example.com" selected="selected">michael@example.com</option>
      <option value="bayjack@example.com">bayjack@example.com</option>
      <option value="stacy@example.com">stacy@example.com</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

On my PHP page, when I var_dump after selecting multiple options:

```
var_dump($_POST['message-from-select']);
```

I only get one string coming through, i.e.:

```
string 'michael@example.com' (length=19)
```

Do I need to go to a hidden input format?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer is to include `[]` after the name attribute, which has little to do with the plugin.

```
<select multiple name="message-from-select[]" id="message-from-select" class="select2">
```